# Can anybody explain what does Math.floor(rc4Rand.getRandomNumber() mean?

Tags: javascript

I understand the math.floor and math.random issue but not in this case rc4Rand.getRamdomNumber(). I checked those similar questions asked before and did not find code related with rc4Rand. Wikipedia mentioned a little bit. If anybody think this is too simple question and this is not the right place to ask here, please kindly let me know from where I can get further information. Tks! It's related with an unfinished task. Students need to finish it. Without full understanding of what does rc4Rand.getRandomNumber generate, it 's hard for me to finish it. The array length is 20. And the code is like this:

```
var first = ["John", "James", "Bill", "Arnold", "Lisa", "Ann", "Kimberly", "Monica"]; 
var last = ["Smith", "Jones", "Williams", "Brown", "Wilson", "Taylor", "Johnson"]; 
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){ 
var n1 = Math.floor(rc4Rand.getRandomNumber() * first.length); 
var n2 = Math.floor(rc4Rand.getRandomNumber() * last.length); 
var nameBirth = first[n1] + " " + last[n2]; 
nameBirth += ", 19" + randint(10) + randint(10); 
document.writeln("Name and birth year:" + nameBirth); 
document.write("Age at 2013: "); 
outputAge(nameBirth); 
} 


function outputAge(nameBirth){
```

Comment: If I understand  correctly, this code generates a random first and lastname (from the array) and creates a year of birth that is between 1900 and 1920 and then calculates its age at 2013?

Comment: `getRandomNumber` returns most likely a float. To access an element in an array you need an integer.

Comment: Tks! As we have many exercises related with rc4Rand. Now I get the idea. When you google it things like that, there is only one webpage mentioned it except Wiki.

Comment: by the way, correct one thing the array length in this case mentioned wrong. It was another  question's length. sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

`rc4Rand` is a PRNG formula you're using as a library.  It generates an answer between 0 and 1.  You're then multiply by a length, so the new number will be between 0 and the length.  Since you are using the floor function, it will round down giving you an integer number between 0 and length.

Answer (score 1):

`rc4Rand.getRandomNumber()` creates a random floating number between 0 and 1. This number then get multiplied by the amount of first names that are defined in your array `first`.

So you actually get a random number between `0` and `first.length`.
Then by using `Math.floor()` you are eliminating the decimals point from the random floating number and you get an integer.

The integer is then used to select a random element from the array `first`.

So basically what it does is:

1. Create random number `0 < x < first.length`.
2. Make an integer out of it, so you can use it to as an index on the array
3. Select random name using the random index you generated

Answer (score 1):

As all the others went in to detail what is happening in your code heres whats RC4.

RC4 itself is a stream cipher. Its used as a random-number-generator whose output is XOR'ed against a text stream. If you are using the standard rand() function the output is predictable. With RC4 it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Produce a number between 0 and 1 (but less than 1):

```
rc4Rand.getRandomNumber()
```

Produce a number between 0 and `first.length` (but less than `first.length`):

```
rc4Rand.getRandomNumber() * first.length
```

Round that number down:

```
Math.floor(rc4Rand.getRandomNumber() * first.length);
```

This produces a random array index within the bounds of the array.